# how to get card information after swapping in android

Tags: android, credit-card, credit-card-track-data

I am working on an application where we are providing user a way to pay bill through credit card but I don't have any idea how/which api should I use to get information of card swapped in android.

Please help.

Thank You

Comment: Have u achieved this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can get the credit card information from the credit card.

1. Scan using android internal camera.
2. Else use the external credit card reader.

1) Two ways you can achieve this.

```
  I) Existing software library.

  For this there is a software library card.io. Check [https://www.card.io/how-it-works/][1].

  They provide you card.io jar file and some of shared libraries. With this you can scan the credit card then they l notify the relevant detail read from the credit card. But now there is a problem in this. They said like the process is going on. 
Download sample link:[http://teck.in/download-card-io-scan-credit-cards-in-android-and-ios.html][2]

   II) You can implement your own credit card scanner by using OCR technology. Check the following link. It might help you in that. [http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/][3].
```

2) For payment also you can use external card reader.

```
  Squareup, Stripe, Scanpay, Magtek,etc... They provide you with their own external card reader. And some of them offer the card in free of cost. Check with these. They guide you to achieve your payment.
```

Hope this would help you.